# Манипуляции с default button

Tags: java, javafx, gui

В Scene имеется три Button. Первая кнопка подсвечивается, как дефолтная кнопка, из-за чего при нажатии стрелок вправо - влево на клавиатуре происходит навигация по этим кнопкам. Как сделать чтобы этого не происходило? Можно ли отключить подсвечивание? Стрелки уже назначены на другие события.

Comment: Решено. Проблема на самом деле была не в default Button а в свойстве  setFocusTraversable(false);